# Quantum GIS Standalone Installer Windows folder

Tags: qgis, windows

Which is the "Quantum GIS Standalone Installer Windows" folder?
Is it, as usual, something like `"c:\program files\quantum gis"`?

I cannot make a test (at this moment) in a Windows machine.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86) on Windows 7

Comment: Thank you. And what's the name of QGIS folder? Is it "Quantum gis"?

Comment: It changes depending on what version you have installed.  I have "C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Copiapo" and "C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the full path is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw

At least, that's what I'm seeing....

Comment: I think on 32 bit machines, that will be C:\Program Files\... (no x86). I also don't have a handy way to test.

Comment: a Google search on ["C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw"](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22C%3A%5CProgram+Files+(x86)%5CQuantum+GIS+Wroclaw%22#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22C%3A%5CProgram+Files%5CQuantum+GIS+Wroclaw%22&pbx=1&oq=%22C:%5CProgram+Files%5CQuantum+GIS+Wroclaw%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4002l4674l0l5241l6l5l0l0l0l4l469l1629l0.1.1.1.2l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=f9ef8465024f9e21&biw=1280&bih=935) seems to show that's correct